# Replace Numpy NaN with string in list with strings

Tags: python, string, list, replace, nan

I have a list containing string elements, and several NaN numpy floats. E.g.

```
l=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'nan']
```

How do I replace the float `nan` to the string `missing`?

Most answers I found regard this issue in a pandas DataFrame.

---

**Try 1:**

```
for x in l:
    x=x.replace('nan', 'missing')
```

gives `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'`

**Try 2:**

```
for x in l:
   if str(x)=='nan':
       x=str(x)
```

Command executes, but nothing changes.

---

**Advised by comments:**

1. `['missing' if x is 'nan' else x for x in l]`
2. `['missing' if x is np.isnan else x for x in l]`
3. `['missing' if x is np.nan else x for x in l]`

Commands execute, but nothing changes.

Comment: `l = [text if text != 'nan' else 'missing' for text in l]` would be one way to do this.

Comment: Note that your code sample contains a string, not a (numpy) NaN.

Comment: If your list contains actuals NaNs together with strings, this can work with a list comprehension: `l = [text if not np.isnan(text) else 'missing' for text in l]`.

Comment: It appears in my list as `nan`. When I want to change, it gives a float error.

Comment: If your list is a numpy array, I'd use numpy array indexing instead: `l[np.isnan(l)] = 'missing'`.

Comment: " When I want to change, it gives a float error.": that doesn't make sense: show your code attempt and the traceback.

Comment: All of the following execute, but do not change a thing: 1) `['missing' if x is 'nan' else x for x in l]`, 2) `['missing' if x is np.isnan else x for x in l]`, 3) `['missing' if x is np.nan else x for x in l]`.

Comment: @Evert, see error.

Comment: The `['missing' if x is np.isnan else x for x in l]` is incorrect. Have a look at my third comment: you need `np.isnan(x)`. Please read some documentation how np.isnan works before blindly copying and trying examples.

Comment: Ah I see. Also, thank you for the kind remark, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a bad format for your NaN's (notice the nan is outputed nan and not 'nan'). The answers from the comment should work:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', np.nan]
>>> print l
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', nan]
>>> l_new=['missing' if x is np.nan else x for x in l]
>>> print l_new
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'missing']
```

For your current problem maybe make the following solution:

```
my_nan=l['some_index_with_nan']
l_new=['missing' if x is my_nan else x for x in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't test for nan using equality (i.e., np.nan==np.nan returns False) and because np.isnan can't handle strings, the best way I found to do this is to change the nan values to strings and then compare.

In a numpy array:

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', np.nan]
>>> print(l)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', nan]

>>> l = np.array(l).astype(str)
>>> print(l)
['foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'nan']

>>> l[l=='nan'] = 'missing'
>>> print(l)
['foo' 'bar' 'baz' 'missing']
```

in a list:

```
>>> l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', np.nan]
>>> print(l)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', nan]

>>> l = ['missing' if str(x)=='nan' else x for x in l]
>>> print(l)
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'missing']
```